# Latex tabularx issue with spacing

Tags: latex

So just trying to edit a table someone had done in tabularx as I liked the style however I have no idea what I'm doing really and as such I've come up against a problem. There is a big space after the entry 'setup', in the below code and I would like it all to be nice and symmetrical the space makes it very asymmetrical. Is there a way to remove this space?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \edef\TabularRowHeight{\the\dimexpr-\arraystretch\baselineskip}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{YY}
    \toprule
    Alice  &  Bob \\
    \midrule
    \emph{Setup}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
    Alice \& Bob select a prime $p$ and a generator $g$ for the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$
    &\\

    &\emph{Private Computation}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
    &  Bob randomly selects $b \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and then computes the following:

     $B \equiv g^b \mod p$ once computed Bob sends Alice $B$

     \\[\TabularRowHeight] & \\

    & \emph{Key Computation}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
    & Bob who now has $A$, calculates the following:$A^b \equiv (g^a)^b \equiv g^{ab} \mod p$

     \\


    \emph{Private Computation}\\ 
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
    Alice randomly selects $a \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and then computes the following:

    $A \equiv g^a \mod p$ once computed Alice sends Bob $A$ & \\ \pagebreak

    \emph{Key Computation}\\ 
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
    Alice who now has $B$, calculates the  following:$B^a \equiv (g^b)^a \equiv g^{ab} \mod p$ & \\


    \bottomrule


    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[Picture of current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLjHn.png)

[Output I'd like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsFCM.png)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the result? I don't get any unusual space other than the empty cells with are explicitly added in the code. Do you maybe want to remove these?

Comment: Perhaps I do want to remove these, I am working out what does what of a similar table not familiar with using this package at all. Will add a picture for you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think removing the alternating layout from the table you showed makes a lot of sense, but here is a try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}
        \emph{Setup}: Alice \& Bob select a prime $p$ and a generator $g$ for the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}YY@{}}
    \toprule
    Alice  &  Bob \\
    \midrule
    \addlinespace[1.2em]
    \emph{Private Computation}:&\\ \addlinespace
%    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(l){2-2}
    Alice randomly selects $a \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and then computes the following:

    $A \equiv g^a \mod p$ once computed Alice sends Bob $A$& Bob randomly selects $b \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and then computes the following:

     $B \equiv g^b \mod p$ once computed Bob sends Alice $B$\\\addlinespace[1.2em]

     \emph{Key Computation}: &\\ \addlinespace
%    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(l){2-2}
    Alice who now has $B$, calculates the  following:$B^a \equiv (g^b)^a \equiv g^{ab} \mod p$  & Bob who now has $A$, calculates the following:$A^b \equiv (g^a)^b \equiv g^{ab} \mod p$
     \\
    \bottomrule


    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead I would prefer a 3-column layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}
        \emph{Setup}: Alice \& Bob select a prime $p$ and a generator $g$ for the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{2.2cm}YY@{}}
    \toprule
    & Alice  &  Bob \\
    \midrule
    \emph{Private \linebreak Computation} & %    
    Alice randomly selects $a \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and then computes the following:

    $A \equiv g^a \mod p$ once computed Alice sends Bob $A$& Bob randomly selects $b \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and then computes the following:

     $B \equiv g^b \mod p$ once computed Bob sends Alice $B$\\\addlinespace
     \emph{Key \linebreak Computation} & Alice who now has $B$, calculates the  following:$B^a \equiv (g^b)^a \equiv g^{ab} \mod p$  & Bob who now has $A$, calculates the following:$A^b \equiv (g^a)^b \equiv g^{ab} \mod p$
     \\
    \bottomrule


    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks just wondering is it possible to have the subheadings for the bob column as well? And to have a horizontal line above the setup? Just looking through the code now trying to work out what's happening. :)

Comment: @Dead_Ling0 Try with `\emph{Private Computation}:&\emph{Private Computation}:\\ \addlinespace`, but having redundant information in your table will decrease the information-to-noise ratio dramatically

Comment: Thank you kindly you've been most helpful, will try to understand what you've done any resources where I can learn about tableux the latex wiki wasn't very helpful.

Comment: @Dead_Ling0 I can recommend https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/index.html for latex beginners. From your question, I think your problem is not really related to `tabularx`, but rather about general mechanics of `tabular` in latex (tabularx is just a special case of a tabular). A short summary: http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/LaTeX/TableHelp1.pdf